# Creating an algorithm for language identification

Tags: java, algorithm, zip, detection

Who knows similar algorithms for finding a language whose logic is similar to this one?
Sprachidentifikation algorithm: The main idea of the algorithm is to compare the difference between the compression of the original text and the compression of the translation of the text into different languages. How are the steps of this algorithm:

Take a short text T, for which translations into many languages are available, and save the translation of Ti into each of these languages.
Determine the length |zip(Ti)| compressed file using the ZIP compression algorithm for each Ti.
Attach the text X under study to each of these translations. You will get a set of strings of the form Ti+X.
The algorithm selects the language for which the difference is |zip(Ti+X)| - |ti(Ti)| is minimal, that is, where Ti+X is compressed in the best way.pt

I tried to find similar sources, but I didn't find them.

Comment: That isn’t language identification, it’s compression size comparison. You may know the language as a side effect. Do you actually want language identification (seems tangential) or are you asking how to compare file sizes?

Comment: Wikipedia ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_identification ) has comparing compression sizes as a method for identifying language; looking more it is possible that it is a suboptimal method and no-one has dared to remove it from that article

Answer (score 0):

what you proposing is unreliable as compression scheme must stay the same which is not guarantied (you might update zip utility at any time which might break your algo) And I think this will work only for Huffman encoding based (or similar letter probability based) encoding so ZIP is not good match as that one uses Lharc which uses combinations of letters.

Simple Language identification is usually done by comparing character histograms...

Each language "beletry" texts has they own probability distribution of ocurrence of each characters so you take long enough input text (does not need to be the same text per language) and compute probability of occurrence of each character in alphabet and use this data as referrence for each language.

Then for unknown text compute the same and just compute distance between it and your known languages which ever is closest is your language...

note that technical literature might have different probabilities in comparison to beletry or poetry or whatever else ... So its best to compute reference probabilities from the same type of literature.

This is usually used in cryptho-graphy to break substitution based ciphers quickly (based on probability of letters you have much less possible combinations of substitutions so the brute force `O(26^26)` will be eased up (the 26 exponent) will be usually (wildly guessed) `~3..10` based on language.

There might be more languages with similar distance in such cases you can add dictionary comparison (have few very common words and search for them like `a,an,the,and` in english to distinguish such languages)